# Restricted access (or sessions) with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I did a kind of "shop" with codeigniter, but now, if I put the link of a function
localhost/shop/insertproduct, I can see everything without login.
How can I make it "private"?
I've been looking some tutorials but don't really understand.
In my index I'm just loading a view, I have a login function and then the other functions (for insert, modify, etc).
If anyone can help me... Thanks!

Here's my function for login

```
public function entrar(){
    $nom= $this->input->post('nom');
    $pass= $this->input->post('pass');

    if($nom && $pass){
        $data['nom']=$nom;
        $data['pass']=$pass;
        $this->load->model('Tienda_model');
        $user=$this->Tienda_model->get_usuario($nom, $pass);

        //var_dump($user);
        if ($user[0]['id']=='1'){
            $resultado = $this->Tienda_model->get_catalogo(); 
            $data['cat']=$resultado;
            $resultado2 = $this->Tienda_model->get_categorias(); 
            $data['cate']=$resultado2;
            $this->parser->parse('admin_view', $data);
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('inicio_view');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your code where you are creating the session

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I edited the original post with the code.

Comment: Are you creating the session anywhere?

Comment: Follow the tutorial http://ericterpstra.com/2013/03/a-sample-codeigniter-application-with-login-and-session/

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-user-registration-login-system/

Comment: The tutorial is several years old and there are some minor issues with it. Redis also may not be available. But the point is still valid, I suppose. You need some kind of authentication system. I don't recommend rolling your own unless you have to. Integrate tank or ion or something.

Comment: Oh, will try those tutorials then, if anything happens, I will tell. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is your goal to have some "views" only available to certain users? If so, you need an authentication system. Take a look at this [tutorial series.](http://avenir.ro/create-cms-using-codeigniter-3/create-admin-area/). It is for a CMS, but the ideas are easily adapted to any site.